# JavaScript function not working with newline / br

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to get some text from a database and show it using Javascript.

**Here is my code:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $content = nl2br($row['content']);
    echo "<a id=\"details\" onclick=\"show_details('{$content}');\"></a>";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">";
    echo "function show_details(id, title, content) {
        alert(content);
    }";
    echo "</script>";
```

Text type is `utf8_general_ci` and when it contains a new line, Javascript does not work!

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Show your rendered javascript. Ie: Show the output that you see in source view in your browser

Comment: You shouldn't keep re-declaring the `show_details` function inside a loop.

Comment: when you echo `<script>` tag in browser, it doesn't render that

Comment: Worst question title ever.

Comment: @Curt : Nothing happens when i click on the link, but when the text has no new line, it works...

Comment: Probably one your main problems is using nl2br on `$content` and then placing that HTMLised variable in HTML without htmlspecialcharing it

Comment: Does the PHP even work? With line breaks inside the string?

Comment: @Aesthete : Sorry bad English...

Comment: Is the alert which is not working, not *javascript* :)

Comment: @wroniasty: Yes php works, but when i click on the link, nothing happens, but if the text does not contain new line, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

define the function once, and obey the parameters. You've just defined id, not content. Content is the 3rd parameter, not the first one.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">"; 
echo "function show_details(id, title, content) { 
  alert(content); 
}"; 
echo "</script>"; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

  $content = nl2br($row['content']); 
  echo "<a id=\"details\" onclick=\"show_details('id', 'title', '$content');\"></a>"; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry! This is a shorter code, in the real one the parameters are correct

Comment: imho I don't like to use inline js. It always makes a mess in the code. You could put the content into a hidden div into the anchor. than create a handler `$('a').click(function(){...})` and receive the content from div `content = $(this).find('div').html()` in the callback function. The content of the callack could be the content of `fce show_detail`

Answer (score 0):

If the text contains an enter, it will render the javascript like this:

```
show_details('piece of
content');
```

This is invalid.

Replace the enters with \n:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $content = $row['content'];
    $content = strreplace("\n", "\\n", $content); // 'escape' breaks.
    $content = strreplace("'", "\\'", $content); // escape quotes.

    ?> 
    <a id="details" onclick="show_details('<?=$content?>');"></a>";
    <?
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">";
function show_details(content) {
    alert(content);
}
</script>;
```

As you can see, I moved the declaration of show_details out of the loop, you will only need it once. I also removed the echo's. You'll loose any HTML syntaxt highlighting and you'll need all the escaping. I think this method is much cleaner.

Comment: Doesn't `nl2br` get rid of all the newlines?

Comment: `nl2br` should make that line `show_details('piece of<br />content');` indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that one. Indeed it does. I removed nl2br, because alerting `<br>` doesn't make sense. If it was to be inserted in the DOM instead, show_details can always replace `\n` with `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off separating your JavaScript and PHP.

So, in your PHP file (or HTML template), set up your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function show_details(id, title, content) {
        alert(content);
    }
</script>
```

**Something else I've noticed:** why does your `show_details` function have three parameters (`id`, `title`, `content`) but your initialising function below only has `content`? **Try removing `id` and `title` for the time being, to see if you can get `content` working.**

Then your PHP could simply be:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $content = nl2br($row['content']);
    echo '<a id="details" onclick="show_details(\'' . $content . '\');"></a>';
}
```

Now, in terms of the new line causing problems, have you tried something like this?

JavaScript addition:

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
  return unsafe
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

PHP:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $content = nl2br($row['content']);
    echo '<a id="details" onclick="show_details(escapeHtml(\'' . $content .'\'));"></a>';
}
```

**Alternatively**, as suggested by comments on this post, you could try using `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` on your PHP's `$content` such as this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $content = htmlentities( nl2br( $row['content']) );
    echo '<a id="details" onclick="show_details(escapeHtml(\'' . $content .'\'));"></a>';
}
```

I'm not convinced this is an encoding problem, but I could certainly be wrong... :)

Comment: Isn't your `escapeHtml` function just like PHP's `htmlentities`? Why not use that?